# Local persistent undo file modeline

Tags: undo-redo, persistent-state, modeline

I have `undodir=~/.vim/undodir` such that persistent-undo history files don't clutter my source code directories.

However, for one particular source file, I'd like to have its persistent-undo history file to be stored in the same directory as the source file itself — such that I could move them together to a different machine and the undo history would portably be still there on the other machine.

It seemed natural to use a modeline for this, so I tried:

```
# vi: undodir=.:undofile
```

But when opening the file, I got:

```
Error detected while processing modelines:
line 1:
E520: Not allowed in a modeline: undodir=.
```

I guess this is because `'undodir'` is a *global* setting...

Now I'm not sure if there is a workable way to do this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the `'undodir'` option cannot be set from a modeline, because it has the ['SECURE'](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/option.c#L2910) flag set.

Since this is a global option, it does not make sense to set this option differently for a specific file, that would also affect all other buffers that are edited later then.

However it might be possible to use a `BufRead` in combination with a `BufWritePost` autocommand to do what you want.. Something similar to this:

```
set undodir=~/tmp/undodir,. undofile
augroup MyUndoDir
  au!
  au BufRead /tmp/foobar.vim :setl noundofile
  au BufWritePost /tmp/foobar.vim  exe "wundo ". fnamemodify(@%, ':h'). '/.'. fnamemodify(@%, ':t'). '.un~'
augroup END
```

Since the `'undofile'` option has been disabled for that buffer whenever we edit it, we need to explicitly write the undofile on an `BufWritePost` autocommand. Of course you need to use the actual filename instead of `/tmp/foobar.vim` in the example.